# Symfony 4 не работает сервис контейнер

Tags: php, symfony

Создаю сервисный класс App\Http\OpenWeather
Пишу в services.yml типа того

```
openweather:
        class: App\Http\OpenWeather
```

ну и в контроллере пытаюсь использовать

```
$weatherService = $this->container->get('openweather');
```

на что получаю ошибку

> Service "openweather" not found: even though it exists in the app's
>   container, the container inside "App\Controller\WeatherController" is
>   a smaller service locator that only knows about the "http_kernel",
>   "parameter_bag", "request_stack", "router" and "session" services. Try
>   using dependency injection instead.

пробовал так же просто вписывать имя класса как аргумент метода типа

```
public function weather(Request $request, OpenWeather $weatherService)
```

На это получил ошибку

> Cannot determine controller argument for
>   "App\Controller\WeatherController::weather()": the $weatherService
>   argument is type-hinted with the non-existent class or interface:
>   "App\Http\OpenWeather".

пробовал просто создать экземпляр

```
$weatherService = new OpenWeather();
```

и тут ошибка

> Attempted to load class "OpenWeather" from namespace "App\Http". Did
>   you forget a "use" statement for another namespace?

хотя я использовал use

Как мне все же использовать нужный мне класс в симфони как сервис?

P.S.
Произошло необьяснимое - переименовал класс OpenWeather в Weather и заработал use и автовайринг. Но вот контейнер не работает все равно

Comment: Возможно Вы не импрортировали Ваш класс `use App\Http\OpenWeather`

Answer (score 1):

В symfony 4.2 поддерживается [автоматическая регистрация](https://symfony.com/doc/4.2/service_container.html#creating-configuring-services-in-the-container), внедрение и оптимизация Ваших сервисов. Пример конфига `config/services.yaml`:

```
services:
    # default configuration for services in *this* file
    _defaults:
        autowire: true      # Automatically injects dependencies in your services.
        autoconfigure: true # Automatically registers your services as commands, event subscribers, etc.
        public: false       # Allows optimizing the container by removing unused services; this also means
                            # fetching services directly from the container via $container->get() won't work.
                            # The best practice is to be explicit about your dependencies anyway.

    # makes classes in src/ available to be used as services
    # this creates a service per class whose id is the fully-qualified class name
    App\:
        resource: '../src/*'
        exclude: '../src/{DependencyInjection,Entity,Migrations,Tests,Kernel.php}'

    # ...
```

> данная конфигурация  делает классы в `src/` доступными для
>   использования в качестве сервисов

И побольшому счету Вам нужно создать сервис

```
namespace App\Service;


class OpenWeather {

...

}
```

Импортировать в каком-нибудь контроллере сервис и вызвать в экшене.

```
use App\Service\OpenWeather

class HomeController {

   private $openWeather;

   public __constructor(OpenWeather $openWeather) {

        $this->openWeather = $openWeather;
   }

   public function weather() {
       $this->openWeather->getWeather();
 ...
   } 
}
```

Comment: @JonnyManowar Хотел бы добавить  к ответу то, что сервис вы не можете вызывать из контейнера напрямую потому что по-умолчанию сервисы создаются приватными. 
Ну и насколько я понимаю что в  контроллере вы получить сервисы можете через сигнатуру action, не добавляя их в конструктор, а вот если вы хотите использовать сервис внутри другого сервиса, тогда описывайте зависимость в конструкторе.